# on default component how to get url parameter in angular

Tags: angular, routes

I want to get url parameter in in default component ie landing page.

I have used routes as given below.

```
export const appRoutes:Routes = [
   {path:':id', component:myComponent}
]
```

And Iam trying to get the value using:

```
this._route.snapshot.params["id"];
```

the url structure will as given below
[image]

[link to project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rgdkrq)

Comment: So what is your issue? Btw, you should use `this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')` which is recommended these days.

Comment: I am not getting value,  path:':id' is correct or not ie {path:':id', component:myComponent}

Comment: Please share more code (how is `_route` defined, etc.) and some context (does this happen when you input the URL manually, when clicking on a link from inside your app, ...?)

Comment: constructor( private url_service:UrlserviceService, private _route:ActivatedRoute) {
    
   }

Comment: You haven't answered my other question, need more context. The snapshot will only give you the initial value of that param, but if `myComponent` already exists and you click a link changing the value of `id`, then you cannot use `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`. Please edit your question (instead of posting new comments) with more info.

Comment: Here's a complete minimal example **not** reproducing the problem: if you append '/42' to the URL, it displays "Hello 42". Fork it, and edit it to make it reproduce the error. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wc4sqx?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: I have added project link above please check..

Comment: You don't have any <router-outlet> directive in your root component. So no route is ever activated. You shouldn't use the root component, which is always displayed in index.html, as the component of your route. Use a separate component.

Comment: Thanks  @JB Nizet for quick response got the mistake.